# How to always write log message to file regardless of level setting

Tags: python, logging

I'm currently implemented a quiet mode in my script using the logging module as follows:

```
quiet = False # set quiet using cmdline arguments
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING if quiet else logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
my_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('file_name')
logger.addHandler(self.file)
```

With the code above, I get the output I wanted to screen, as well as to file in a non-quiet mode, like:

```
logger.debug('want to show every time in file, but never to console')
logger.info('always in file, but only show in console if not quiet')
logger.warning('Show in both file and console, EVERY TIME')
```

However, if I turn on the quiet mode, I don't get any output to both my screen and my file.
I want EVERYTHING in my log file regardless whether it's quiet or not, but only print to screen if it is not quiet mode (basically, always write to file regardless of the logging level, but print based on logging level).

Please tell me how can I do that.

**EDIT:**

I made a more clear posts on the desired behavior for each level differences. In the answers provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837615/different-levels-of-logging-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911737/using-python-logging-module-to-info-messages-to-one-file-and-err-to-another-file?rq=1), setting FileHandler level doesn't seem to help in my case as I always want to write debug level information to the file.

```
quiet = False # set quiet using cmdline arguments
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING if quiet else logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
my_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('file_name')
my_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)       # added setLevel
logger.addHandler(self.file)

logger.debug('abcde')     # this doesn't show in file or console as my basicConfig
                          # is logging.INFO
                          # But i WANT it to
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911737/using-python-logging-module-to-info-messages-to-one-file-and-err-to-another-file?rq=1

Comment: @Pavel My question is different from those posts. Those posts ask for writing ERROR message to file while the logging level setting is below that (INFO), while I ask for writing lower logging level to a file while my logging level setting is higher. The fileHandler.setLevel() doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need level control at the handlers only, but not the logger. So:

1. Set the logger level to the lowest level you need (e.g. `INFO`).
2. Set the console handler (`StreamHandler`) level to whatever is indicated by `quiet`.
3. Don't set a level on the `FileHandler`, so that it will process all messages passed by the logger.

You can't use `basicConfig()` for this (it only sets the level on the root logger, not on handlers) - use `dictConfig()` or use the API calls (`addHandler`, `setLevel` etc.)